# Cannot change zoom level parameter dynamically within gdal2tiles call in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal2tiles

I am trying to do the following but it is falling over i.e. (has no error message
and doesnt start the tiling process). I think the parsing of the zoom level argument is falling over. I havent been able to parse the zoom level

NB. the vrtName variable contains the zoomLevel as string "0-5", "5-10", or "10-18" which was taken from the vrt names 0-5.vrt, 5-10.vrt and 10-18.vrt

```
data = vrtName.split("-")

minZoomLevel = data[0]

maxZoomLevel = data[1]

print("gdal2tiles tiling process started.....")

os.system('python "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal2tiles.py" -p geodetic -z ' + str(minZoomLevel) + '-' + str(maxZoomLevel) + ' C:/Marine/mosaic_tif/' + vrtName + '.tif ' + outputFolder + clientName + str(n)) n = n + 1
```

Is it possible to change the zoom level parameter dynamically in a gdal2tiles call within python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that os.system can't parse your -z parameter because when summing all the string you give to console I get (placing 6 to minZoomLevel and 10 to maxZoomLevel):

```
os.system('python "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal2tiles.py" -p geodetic -z 6-10 C:/Marine/mosaic_tif/name.tif ' + outputFolder + clientName + str(n))
```

but the correct is -z "6-10".

As for me, for tiling I use python library [gdal2tiles](https://pypi.org/project/gdal2tiles/) - this is very convenient and understandable! You can pass parameters as a dict or directly in function calling

Comment: Hi Jane, you're an absolute LEGEND! You saved my bacon! That has worked i.e. putting the zoom level within "" such as  zoomLevel = repr(vrtName)  and then adding to   os.system('python "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal2tiles.py" -p geodetic -z ' + zoomLevel + ' C:/Marine/mosaic_tif/name.tif ' + outputFolder + clientName + str(n)). Just wondering how to know how zoom levels to specify are determined? Is there a rule of thumb to know what zoom level is best to use? I am new to working with raster data. Grateful for any useful links. Best Regards Dave

Comment: I used the first approach as my GDAL is a mess. I am working on Windows 10 and tried to call "from geo import gda"l within python to then use gdal2tiles within python itself rather than have to use the gdal2tiles called through os.system but was not able to resolve my OSGeo4W and python installation issues. Dave

Comment: Hi @daveb!) See here https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels for  ~ ratio between level and scale. For me this link https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames was very useful for understanding tiles and tiling

Comment: I also had many issues while installing gdal inside python. Eventually I have succesfully installed library pygdal, that satisfies my gdal version - and now I am able to call gdal2tiles.generate_tiles(input_tif, destination, **options)

Comment: Thanks for the links Jane! Much appreciated.I was wondering if a zoom level is not specified if gdal2tiles works out the optimal zoom level to use?. Also I am unsure why/when to use a zoom level of say 5 over 0-5 or 1-5 or 10-18 or 18. Very confused. What does these instances mean? With regards to the marine charts geotiff data I have they are at various map scales. Do you know if it is feasible to combine TMS data resources folders of map tiff tiled with 0-5 zoom with other TMS data resources that were created from tiling a different map tif that used 5-10 zoom? Is this at all feasible? Dave

Comment: I am selecting charts of the same scale within an area of interest and tiling with a specified zoom level which creates one set of TMS data resources (Folders). Then from the same Area of Interest I am selecting charts of another map scale and tiling based on another zoom level. From the resulting TMS data resources created by gdal2tiles is it possible to combine the folders from both sets of tiling to create one TMS folder and one map viewer html to view all the tiled tifs above? I am not sure this is feasible?

Comment: Yes, if zoom levels are not specified, gdal2tiles determines the optimal zoom levels, depending on pixelsize and resolution (meters/pixel)  but not always what needed - I mean the cases when map .tiff resolution is not really satisfies the map scale. zooms 0-5 is for small-scale charts, e.g. maps of large regions, continents or oceans (scale less than 1:15 mln), but zoom > 10 is for cities, districts, etc. I have never used levels more than 14 because it is very high-detailed

Comment: Yes, It is feasible to combine different tile folders created by gdal2tiles - if zooms are not intersects it is just coping to one folder, but in case common zooms you have to merge tiles pixels together as images in loop try  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297235/8129993 hope it helps!